# What does the special form ${varname:-text} do in shell script?

Tags: shell

I came across this expression ${varname:-text},And 3 other similar forms:

`${varname-text}`

`${varname:=text}`

`${varname:?text}`

It seems like text substitution, how to use this expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [standards document for the POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) explains these special parameter expansion formats thusly:

```
${parameter:-word}
```

> **Use Default Values**. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of
>   word shall be substituted; otherwise, the value of parameter shall be
>   substituted.

```
${parameter:=word}
```

> **Assign Default Values**. If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of
>   word shall be assigned to parameter. In all cases, the final value of
>   parameter shall be substituted. Only variables, not positional
>   parameters or special parameters, can be assigned in this way.

```
${parameter:?[word]}
```

> **Indicate Error if Null or Unset**. If parameter is unset or null, the
>   expansion of word (or a message indicating it is unset if word is
>   omitted) shall be written to standard error and the shell exits with a
>   non-zero exit status. Otherwise, the value of parameter shall be
>   substituted. An interactive shell need not exit.

There are examples given there and a more complete table.  All POSIX-compliant shells must support them.  Some, [like `bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), include additional formats.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, So all three form don't do anything when parameter exist and have value, do they?